# Scroll bxslider to the div which contains the ID

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I am stuck on a complicated thing about bxslider.

I have a calendar with events wrapped into bxslider, with 2 months wrapped into one slide.

Now I have an option where the user can go to a particular year say for example 2016.

I know there is a function goToSlide where you can scroll the slider to a particular slide, but how can I know which slide element it should be scrolled to ?

I have made it on jsfiddle so here is the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/q17a907g/4/

```
var slider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 2,
    moveSlides: 2,
    slideMargin: 10,
    slideSelector: '.slide',
});

jQuery("#scroll").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var syear = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    var slidediv = 'calendar-'+ syear +'-01';
    alert(slidediv);
    slider.goToSlide(slidediv);
});
```

Comment: goToSlide(index) ,supports index, check the doc http://bxslider.com/options

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

OP >I know there is a function goToSlide where you can scroll the slider to a particular slide, but how can I know which slide element it should be scrolled to ?

The bxSlider uses an index to keep track of each slide. In addition to it's standard way previously mentioned, it uses the `data-` attribute for the pager (by default the pager appears as navigation dots). Since you're concern is with IDs the latter is probably what interests you the most. IMO, using an array or HTMLCollection (indices of slides) is better because of the potential of using the content dynamically, it is difficult to use a multitude of unique IDs and it becomes inflexible as your content grows.

I hope I set you on the right path, and let me know if I'm not groking your question.

**UPDATE 1**
OK, in a hurry. Take a look it works gr8. you need to fill the rest of the months. good luck
It's so simple you probably overthought it:

```
`slider.goToSlide(idx);`
```

idx is a 0-index number that represents the position of a slide.

```
    jQuery("#scroll").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        slider.goToSlide(1);
    });
```

<del>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/snnb96fv/)</del>

```js
$(function() {
  var slider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 1,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 10,
    slideSelector: '.slide'
  });


  jQuery("#date").change(function(e) {
    var idx = this.value

    slider.goToSlide(idx);
  });

});
```

```css
.bx-prev {
  left: -50px !important;
}
.bx-next {
  right: -50px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

<div id="slider">
  <div id="c0" class="slide">November 2015</div>
  <div id="c1" class="slide">December 2015</div>
  <div id="c2" class="slide">January 2016</div>
  <div id="c3" class="slide">Febuary 2016</div>
  <div id="c4" class="slide">March 2016</div>
  <div id="c5" class="slide">April 2016</div>
</div>
<fieldset>

  <select id="date" name="date">
    <option value="0">November 2015</option>
    ....
    <option value="5">April 2016</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I know that part. but the question is completely different, i want to scroll it to 2016, or let's put it this way, what if there is months too, like i want to scroll it to may 2016.

Comment: You should be more specific, I had something like that made, but I was thinking you might not want that much functionality. I have to go to work, I'll write a quick **UNTESTED** snippet from what I remember.